# Jquery doesn't find dynamicaly dom parent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, smarty

I have to develop a very large platform and I need some improvements in some plugins.

Basically, I have a template which use smarty as engine (it doesn't matter this) and I have this code in that template:

```
<div class="imageLoader">
  <div id="main_picture" data-instance="article" data-location="{$smarty.session.CONFIG.DIR.C_PHOTOS_DIR}">
    {if $data.main_picture}
    <input type='hidden' name='main_picture' value="{$data.main_picture}" />
    <img src="{$smarty.session.CONFIG.DIR.C_PHOTOS_DIR}{$data.main_picture}" />
    <span class="NTPDelete" onclick="javascript: ntpDeleteImage(this);">
    {$smarty.session.language.ntp.delete}
    </span>
    {else}
    <span class="NTPOpenLoader" onclick='javascript: ntpOpenLoader(this);'>
    {$smarty.session.language.ntp.add}
    </span>
    {/if}
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also a js script which contains this code:

```
    function ntpDeleteImage(elem) {
        var parent = $(elem).parent();
        var szInstanceName = $(parent).attr('data-instance');

        var params = {
                'filename' : encodeURI($(parent).find('input').val()),
                'instance': szInstanceName
        };

        $.post("./ajax/ntp.delete.php", params, function(data){
        })

        .done(function(data){
            $(parent).find('img, span').remove();
            $(parent).find('input').val('');

            $("<span />", {
                class: 'NTPOpenLoader'
            }).html(ntpAddPictureText).appendTo(parent);

            $(parent).on('click', 'span.NTPOpenLoader', function(){
                ntpOpenLoader(elem);
            });
        });
    }

function ntpOpenLoader(elem){
    var parent = $(elem).parent();
    var szInstanceName = $(parent).attr('data-instance');

    console.log(parent);

    window.open("ntp.loader.php?id=" + parent[0].id + "&amp;instance=" + szInstanceName, "_blank", "width=400,height=170,top="+event.clientY+",left="+(event.clientX-150));
}
```

Method `ntpOpenLoader()` have two contexts: first is the method ntpDeleteImage and the second is directly from template code (see template code above).

When I run `ntpOpenLoader()` directly from template code it works fine.
When I run `ntpOpenLoader()` from `ntpDeleteImage()` context my span dom doesn't see the parent. Actually, I don't think that my span (with NTPOpenLoader class) retrieve correctly the parent.

Debugging this from Chrome I have in console as follow:

1. In (template context) console return.
   [div#main_picture, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: span.NTPOpenLoader]
2. In context of running from ntpDeleteImage I have:
   [prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: span.NTPOpenLoader]

[image: demonstration]

This means I have an object without parent.
Please help me find my error and also correct me where I'm wrong.

Comment: I forgot to mention that Chrome throw this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `id` of undefined. This cames out in line 6 of ntpOpenLoader() method, where I have parent[0].id. Same code working fine in template context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm was totally idiot to forgot the context of elem inside of onclick event binding. The correct call is ntpOpenLoader(this). Now it's work perfectly.

Thanks folks!